# How to reset cmd colours

Tags: windows, command-line, colors

I had configured custom colours for the Git Bash, which runs inside a regular `cmd` window. Now I want to remove those settings, because I want to use one colour scheme for my entire system.

I deleted every subkey of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` (which did include a “Git Bash” key), and then the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` itself. I also deleted every `Console` key in `HKEY_USERS`. The regular `cmd` console has indeed been reset, but the Git Bash `cmd` instance *still* uses my custom colours after I log off and on again. Where are those colours stored, and how can I delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that Windows also stores console preferences in shortcuts. Deleting the shortcut and creating a new shortcut resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Color`.

Use `color /?` to see all the commands.

> COLOR - If no argument is given, this command restores the color to what it was
>   when CMD.EXE started.  This value either comes from the current console
>   window, the /T command line switch or from the DefaultColor registry
>   value.

Comment: `COLOR` does reset how the colours are used, but the actual colours that are displayed are still those configured in the [properties](http://www.wikihow.com/Image:Change-Colours-in-Command-Prompt-Step-9.jpg). I meant resetting those colours.